# Unit test : Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, karma-jasmine

Below unit test is throwing error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined. How can this be resolved?

component.Ts code

//Input value from parent

```
@Input() path: treeDataKey;
ngOnInit() {
  this.getTestPlanData(this.testId);
  this.testPath = (this.path).toString().replace(/,/g,' /');
}
getTestPlanData(param:any) {
  //Do something
}
```

component.spec.ts

```
it('should call getTestPlanData', () => {
    expect(component.getTestPlanData).toHaveBeenCalled;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try This:

```
import {isUndefined} from "util";

  this.testPath = (this.path && !isUndefined(this.path))?
  (this.path).toString().replace(/,/g,' /'):'';
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a default value to that `@Input()` variable depending on your `treeDataKey` type.

What will this do is, if you donot have the value from `input`, it will get assigned with an `empty value`.
So, if the `parent component` is not instantiated at the time of test, the test runs with a default value.

```
@Input() path: treeDataKey = "";
ngOnInit() {
  this.getTestPlanData(this.testId);
  this.testPath = (this.path).toString().replace(/,/g,' /');
}
getTestPlanData(param:any) {
  //Do something
}
```